# javascript onclick form function

Tags: javascript

Helllo I have this form that take 3 different input for my app.
I try to send that information to my database using `API` but first I want to print it out in the console to see if I got the value from the input but nothing happen, here is my `Javascript` code:

```js
function insertDBs() {
    console.log("hiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii" + document.getElementById('chname').value);
    console.log("hiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii" + document.getElementById('chid').value);
    console.log("hiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii" + document.getElementById('chtoken').value);
    let channelName = document.getElementById('chname').value;
    let channelId = document.getElementById('chid').value;
    let channelAccessToken = document.getElementById('chtoken').value;

    console.log(channelName);
    console.log(document.getElementById('chid').value);
    console.log(channelAccessToken);
}
```

```html
<form name="lineform" action="" method="POST" onsubmit="insertDB()">
   <div>
      <p class="labels required">Channel Name:</p>
      <p class="labels"><input type="text" id="chname" name="chname" value="" placeholder="Enter your Channel Name" style="width: 700px;" required></p>
   </div>
   <br>
   <div>
      <p class="labels required">Channel Id:</p>
      <p class="labels "><input type="text" id="chid" name="chid" value="" placeholder="Enter your Channel ID" style="width: 700px;" required></p>
   </div>
   <br>
   <div>
      <p class="labels required">Channel Access Token:</p>
      <p class="labels "><input type="text" id="chtoken" name="chtoken" value="" placeholder="Enter your Channel Access Token" style="width: 700px;" required></p>
   </div>
   <br>
   <div>
      <button onclick = "insertDBs()" style="background-color:#1f73b7; color:white; width:8%; height: 35px; border: none; border-radius: 3px;" type="submit">Submit</button>
   </div>
   <br>
</form>
```

Any ideas? Many thanks.

Comment: As the button’s type is submit and it is a part of a form, clicking it submits the form and onclick function is not triggered. Try network tab of developer tools of your browser to see what is submitted. Or remove type=submit temporarily for testing. Or remove the form altogether and use ajax to submit info to api.

Comment: @lastr2d2 there is no error. It is a feature not a bug.

Comment: @PanhaSeav Before you made an edit, it was an issue with "chId" and not "chid", which was leading to error in fetching values :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue Identified

1. The form submit event function name is `insertDB` and function name that you defined is `insertDBs`
2. Use event `preventDefault` and `stopPropagation` function to stop form reload.
3. Donot ues `onclick` and type `submit` for the same button. They both are doing the same task.

*Updated Code*

```js
function insertDBs(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
  console.log(
    "hiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii" + document.getElementById("chname").value
  );
  console.log(
    "hiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii" + document.getElementById("chid").value
  );
  console.log(
    "hiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii" + document.getElementById("chtoken").value
  );
  let channelName = document.getElementById("chname").value;
  let channelId = document.getElementById("chid").value;
  let channelAccessToken = document.getElementById("chtoken").value;

  console.log(channelName);
  console.log(document.getElementById("chid").value);
  console.log(channelAccessToken);
}
```

```html
<form name="lineform" action="" method="POST" onsubmit="insertDBs(event)">
  <div>
    <p class="labels required">Channel Name:</p>
    <p class="labels">
      <input
        type="text"
        id="chname"
        name="chname"
        value=""
        placeholder="Enter your Channel Name"
        style="width: 700px;"
        required
      />
    </p>
  </div>
  <br />
  <div>
    <p class="labels required">Channel Id:</p>
    <p class="labels ">
      <input
        type="text"
        id="chid"
        name="chid"
        value=""
        placeholder="Enter your Channel ID"
        style="width: 700px;"
        required
      />
    </p>
  </div>
  <br />
  <div>
    <p class="labels required">Channel Access Token:</p>
    <p class="labels ">
      <input
        type="text"
        id="chtoken"
        name="chtoken"
        value=""
        placeholder="Enter your Channel Access Token"
        style="width: 700px;"
        required
      />
    </p>
  </div>
  <br />
  <div>
    <button
      style="background-color:#1f73b7; color:white; width:8%; height: 35px; border: none; border-radius: 3px;"
      type="submit"
    >
      Submit
    </button>
  </div>
  <br />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to prevent executing the default function. Also do not use onClick method with button type submit

```js
function insertDBs(event) {
        event.preventDefault()
    console.log("hiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii" + document.getElementById('chname').value);
    console.log("hiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii" + document.getElementById('chid').value);
    console.log("hiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii" + document.getElementById('chtoken').value);
    let channelName = document.getElementById('chname').value;
    let channelId = document.getElementById('chid').value;
    let channelAccessToken = document.getElementById('chtoken').value;

    console.log(channelName);
    console.log(document.getElementById('chid').value);
    console.log(channelAccessToken);
}
```

```html
<form name="lineform" action="" method="POST" onsubmit="insertDBs(event)">
        <div>
           <p class="labels required">Channel Name:</p>
           <p class="labels"><input type="text" id="chname" name="chname" value="" placeholder="Enter your Channel Name" style="width: 700px;" required></p>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div>
           <p class="labels required">Channel Id:</p>
           <p class="labels "><input type="text" id="chid" name="chid" value="" placeholder="Enter your Channel ID" style="width: 700px;" required></p>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div>
           <p class="labels required">Channel Access Token:</p>
           <p class="labels "><input type="text" id="chtoken" name="chtoken" value="" placeholder="Enter your Channel Access Token" style="width: 700px;" required></p>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div>
           <button style="background-color:#1f73b7; color:white; width:8%; height: 35px; border: none; border-radius: 3px;" type="submit">Submit</button>
        </div>
        <br>
     </form>
```